# mediaItems missing from Media.ListCustomerMediaItems

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api, oauth2-playground

When sending the GET request to the following URI
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/XXXX/locations/YYYY/media/customers

i get a response that consists of 'nextPageToken' with token for next page, and 'totalMediaItemCount' which says '30' because that's the number of customer media items in the account i use.

According to the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media.customers/list

i am supposed to get this response:

```
{
  "mediaItems": [
    {
      object (MediaItem)
    }
  ],
  "totalMediaItemCount": integer,
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

but even though it says that i have 30 customer media items, the 'mediaItems' is missing from the response.

is there a problem with the API or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried other locations as well or just the one?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have other locations with customer photos. but, if instead of `/media/customers` i send the request to `/media` i do get the images uploaded by that business itself, the response is complete with 'mediaItems' parameter. but when i send the request to `/media/customers` i only get the images count but the mediaItems array is missing.

Comment: Could be a bug, have you tried contacting the API support yet? https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default